# error in embeding html tags in php

Tags: php

```
 <?php   

    $id=16;
    echo '<td><a class="btn btn-primary" href="edit_news.php?id=$id"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-fw"></i> Edit</a></td>';
 ?>
```

I have a search program that performs search via ajaX,whwre i need to embed html tag with php. Search works fine but when i click on edit button the id cant pass on another page. It shows that`http://localhost/web/edit_news.php?id=$id`. But i cant get the id=16. And error shows `Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\web\edit_news.php on line 9`. what is the error in my code?
Can any one help me to solve this?

Comment: Please show us **all** (*relevant parts*) of the code. Your error indicates a `mysql_` query, which you've not shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have change `"edit_news.php?id=$id"` to `"edit_news.php?id='.$id.'"`. Because data in double quotes treated it like string. or you can use single quotes `'`. like `href='edit_news.php?id=$id'`.

```
<?php

    $id=16;
    echo '<td><a class="btn btn-primary" href="edit_news.php?id='.$id.'"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-fw"></i> Edit</a></td>';
?>
```

Comment: Did you read the question? `Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\web\edit_news.php on line 9`

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ yeah, this error might be due to `id` which is not transmitting to the particular page. So the query is not fetching the results.

Answer (score 0):

just change it quote like `'` to `"` and `"` to `'`

```
<?php
$id=16;
echo "<td><a class='btn btn-primary' href='edit_news.php?id=$id'><i class='fa fa-pencil fa-fw'></i> Edit</a></td>";
?>
```

OR

```
<?php
$id=16;
echo '<td><a class="btn btn-primary" href="edit_news.php?id='.$id.'"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-fw"></i> Edit</a></td>';
?>
```

Comment: Did you read the question? `Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\web\edit_news.php on line 9`

Comment: yes but he has also told that he didn't get value of `$id` like `id = 16`

Comment: @Ishan Shah no bdy ,actually i am new in this site so i thought that ,i can accept multiple answer. But then i gave first mark who answered me first

Comment: Ok but he has also changed his answer after i have given so may be my answer was right there . but no problem. have a good luck with programing

Answer (score 0):

Change the single quote with double and double with single Like this :

```
<?php
$id=16;
echo "<td><a class='btn btn-primary' href='edit_news.php?id=$id'><i class='fa fa-pencil fa-fw'></i> Edit</a></td>";
?>
```

Comment: Did you read the question? `Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\web\edit_news.php on line 9`